# Extract Float Values from String in Python (and possibly using Regex)

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am having problem creating a function that takes a string containing length values (eg: '32.0 mm / 1.259"`) and returning just the value in *mm*.

My current function `parse` is only able to handle strings that have just the *mm* value, but not if both *mm* and *inches* value exist.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Regex pattern:** `re.sub("[^0-9.\-]", "", str)`

```py
import re

def parse(str):
    if not str:
        return None
    str = str.lower()
    return float(re.sub("[^0-9.\-]", "", str))

tests = ['12.3 mm', '12.3mm', '32.0 mm / 1.259"', '32.0mm / 1.259"']
for s in tests: 
    print( parse(s) )
```

**Expected Output**

```
12.3
12.3
32.0
32.0
```

**Actual Output**

```
12.3
12.3
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '32.01.259'
```

Comment: Could you please have a look at the answers and choose the one that worked best for you? There are solutions like 1) remving all starting with `mm`, 2) extracting numbers before `mm`. [My solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58418070/3832970) is very similar to [Daniel's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58416297/3832970), but it does not extract the number in case of `5. mmorph`. since I am using a word boundary and my solution will also work in case of integer numbers before `mm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may actually tell regex to capture a float/int value that is right before a `mm` whole word:

```
re.search(r"([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)\s*mm\b", text.lower())
```

See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/jdvU3N/1).

Here,

- `([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)` - Group 1: 1+ digits followed with an optional sequence of `.` and 1+ digits
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `mm\b` - `mm` and a word boundary.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Qs5lpu):

```
import re

def parse(text):
    if not text:
        return None
    match = re.search(r"([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)\s*mm\b", text.lower())
    if match:
        return float(match.group(1))
    return text

tests = ['12.3 mm', '12.3mm', '32.0 mm / 1.259"', '32.0mm / 1.259"']
for s in tests: 
    print( parse(s) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Just simplify your regex pattern to the following:

```
re.sub("mm.*", "", str)
```

... and you'll the expected output

Answer (score 1):

You could search for the matching pattern instead of using sub, for example:

```
import re


def parse(s):
    if not s:
        return None
    s = s.lower()
    return float(re.search("(\d+\.\d*\s*)mm", s).group(1))


tests = ['12.3 mm', '12.3mm', '32.0 mm / 1.259"', '32.0mm / 1.259"']

print([parse(test) for test in tests])
```

**Output**

```
[12.3, 12.3, 32.0, 32.0]
```